# SVN not listed in RAD

Tags: svn, rad, subclipse

I have updated SVN in RAD by the following links "http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.2.x".

But it is not listed in RAD. Can you help me how to check whether it is installed correctly?

Comment: What is RAD? Can you describe it in more detail?

Comment: RAD- Rational Application Developer. Im using "IBM Rational® Application Developer™ for WebSphere® Software Version: 7.5.0"

Answer (score 0):

I could install SVN in IBM RAD by following the links but it had to be done in a certain order. If you post more on where exactly you are then we can tell you what you should download. The update is possible to do from the help..install software option and then the SVN gets accessible from the team... menu item. To install and make SVN work with RAD one must install the pieces of software in this particular order and then it will work.